# When does $IJ=(I+J)(I\cap J)$

Tags: ideals

It's clear that $IJ\supset(I+J)(I\cap J)$, but when is the reverse inclusion true?
So far, the simplest counterexample I could find was $I=(x), J=(x^2,y)$ in $k[x,y]$.

Comment: for instance, when I and J are co-maximal.

Comment: Sure, but that's a very specific case. For instance, it looks like in every PID the result holds.